# Linq: Ignore non joinable items from two lists without throwing error?

Tags: linq, list, join

In the code below, the two lists are joined on Index. But either list could have more items than the other and i just want to join up to the list with the least items and throw the rest out from the other list. So, if list 1 has 5 items and list 2 has 7 items, I want to join both up to item 5, and ignore list 2's remaining items. (and vice versa)

```
var joinLbxs = lbxShtCols.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Select((xlFldList, index) => new
    {
        xlFldList,
        tblFldList = lbxSqlTablesCols.Items[index]
    });
```

Comment: So you want to zip them together? Are you using .NET 4.0. It has a `Zip` extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Steven suggested in a comment, if you are using .Net 4.0, use the [`Zip()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx). If you don't, you could use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) to provide the same functionality.

Or you could do it yourself (assuming both lists are `IList<T>` and have fast indexer):

```
from i in Enumerable.Range(0, new[] { list1.Count, list2.Count }.Min())
select new
{
    item1 = list1[i],
    item2 = list2[i]
}
```

Comment: This does it, thanks!! I used new List<int> instead of new[].

Answer (score 2):

Zip is not too complicated to implement by yourself.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TSource, TOther, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TOther> other,
    Func<TSource, TOther, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var e1 = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (var e2 = other.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try intersecting the 2 lists; that'll give you the common items. `Take()` the number smallest of the 2 lists that you want. It's not clear whether you know which list would have the smallest (by convention), so decide that beforehand. Optionally sort the list if you need BEFORE the `Take()`.

```
int numToTake = (lbxShtCols.Count >= lbxSqlTablesCols.Count)
                ?lbxShtCols.Count
                :lbxSqlTablesCols.Count;

var commons = lbxShtCols.Intersect(lbxSqlTablesCols)
                        .Take(numToTake);
```

Comment: From the sample code, it seems he doesn't want intersection, but zip.

Comment: Random downvoter: why the -1 without your explanation? The OP left the question WIDE open to solutions. The heart of the question is *finding similarities* between 2 collections. How does this answer NOT solve that problem?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to Intersect.

Comment: if the smaller list is always a subset of the bigger list, this would be a right answer, +1, but then the take would also be unessesary

Comment: the downvoter was me, I think the code in the question was clear on what it was doing and your code does something completely different.